# How Can I Do This ORACLE Statement in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
SELECT COUNT(Field1_) 
           FROM 
           (
               SELECT Field1_
               FROM Table1_
               WHERE Field1_= @Field1
           UNION ALL
               SELECT Field1_
               FROM Table2_
               WHERE DeliveryPoint_ = @Field1
           UNION ALL
               SELECT Table3_
               FROM GasSupplied_
               WHERE DeliveryPoint_ = @Field1
           UNION ALL
               SELECT Table4_
               FROM Gnsnominations_
               WHERE DeliveryPoint_ = @Field1
           UNION ALL
               SELECT Table5_
               FROM HourlyProfileReports_
               WHERE DeliveryPoint_ = @Field1
           )
```

And I have problems with this code. Please help me.

```
DECLARE
              CountedRows NUMBER;
            BEGIN
              SELECT COUNT(*) INTO CountedRows 
              FROM Profiles_ 
              WHERE Field1_ = @Param1 AND RowNum < 2;  
                IF(CountedRows > 0)
                THEN
                    UPDATE Profiles_ 
                    SET 
                        Field2_ = @Param2,
                        Field3_ = @Param3,
            Field4_ = @Param4 
                        WHERE Field1_ = @Param1;
                ELSE
                INSERT INTO Profiles_
                (
                    Field1_, 
                    Field2_,
                    Field3_,
                    Field4_
                ) 
                VALUES
                (
                    @Param1, 
                    @Param2,
                    @Param3,
                    @Param4                    );
                END IF;
              END;
```

Please help me. I read many books and tutorials but I can't understand this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first one needs a table alias

```
SELECT COUNT(Field1_) 
           FROM 
           (
               SELECT Field1_
               <snip>
               WHERE DeliveryPoint_ = @Field1
           ) AS foo
```

Your second one should begin

```
            DECLARE CountedRows int;


              SELECT CountedRows = COUNT(*) 
              FROM Profiles_ 
              WHERE Field1_ = @Param1 AND RowNum < 2;
```

To be syntactically correct. Also use `END;` not `END IF;` However it gives you a potential race condition. As you are on SQL Server 2008 you should look into `MERGE` for doing this kind of `UPSERT`

As far as I can see the whole of the second one can be replaced with.

```
MERGE INTO Profiles_
USING (VALUES(@Param1_) )T(P1)
ON Field1_ = P1
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET Field2_ = @Param2_,
             Field3_ = @Param3_,
             Field4_ = @Param4_
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
  INSERT
  VALUES (P1, @Param2_, @Param3_, @Param4_);
```

Answer (score 0):

Set command is preferred over the select command. So, instead you should pay homage to the select command and code it as

```
set countedRows = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Profiles_ );
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!